# Get the value from string vecotr and store in another string?

Tags: string, visual-c++, vector, stl, mfc

I am trying to store the string value into vector. And then after storing I want to store in string one by one. In first step split the sting by "," and store into vector. And again try to retrive and get into string.

My code:

```
CString sAssocVal = "test1, test2, test3";

istringstream ss( sAssocVal.GetBuffer(sAssocVal.GetLength()) );

vector<string> words;


string token;
while( std::getline(ss, token, ',') )
{
    words.push_back( token );
}
```

Try to again retrive from vector:

```
for(int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++)
        std::string st= words[i];
```

But the value of st is getting NULL always.

where I am missing some thing.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking what your vector contains before the loop? What do you mean by "getting NULL"? How do you observe this?

Comment: I always avoid using MFC's `CString` as much as possible, problem might in a way you construct your `istringstream`, have you tried to output `ss.str()` ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the problem is the istringstream initialization, a small modification makes your example work:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/698818655cbba4e7

You could first convert CString to std::string, there are a lot of topics about that problem

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this is by using this code.

```
   CString st;
    for(int i = 0; i<words.size(); i++)
            st= words[i].c_str();
```